# How to update all fields in a Word document?

Tags: c#

I want to update all fields of the Microsoft Word document. Currently i am using method Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document.Fields.Update() but it is not updating fields. But if I do the same thing manually by selecting total document content and press window key f9 to update fields then fields of the Microsoft Word Document are updating properly.

So Can some one suggest me is there any other way to update the Fields of word document?

Comment: What is the error message or exception you are getting?update your question more information with code what you have tried .

Comment: I am not getting any error or exception.I have to update word document Fields before i start using it in my application to get proper result out of it. As Fields are not updating properly I am getting wrong results. But when i did manual updation of fields in document i got proper result. Here is the code snippet I am using in my application.

wordDoc.Fields.Update();
wordDoc.UndoClear();

wordDoc is Microsoft word interop object.

Comment: so the error may not from com methods. it will be from your code where you manipulating data in the word document.

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of updating the tables of contents/figures:

```
// Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document;

foreach (TableOfContents tableOfContents in document.TablesOfContents)
{
    tableOfContents.Update();
}
foreach (TableOfFigures tableOfFigures in document.TablesOfFigures)
{
    tableOfFigures.Update();
}
foreach (Range storyRange in document.StoryRanges)
{
    storyRange.Fields.Update();
}
```

I hope this covers the fields you need to update, or gives you enough information to extrapolate to your fields.

Comment: Document fields are not updating with these conditions. But one thing I have observed is, if I save the document after updating fields using below code snippet then i am able to see expected result.   _wordDoc.Fields.Update();
_wordDoc.UndoClear();  _wordDoc.Save();  But I dont want to save the document as saving of document may effect on document original content.

Comment: `foreach (var field in m_document.Fields.Cast<Word.Field>()) { field.Update(); }` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new paragraph, be sure you add it at the end of the previous paragraph, then your fields will update. Do NOT add the new paragraph at the beginning of the current paragraph. See example:

2.00 Paragraph End (Press "Enter" here for a new Paragraph 2.01)
2.01 (Do NOT press "Enter" here) Beginning of Paragraph